# How to reset event_data with a shiny button?

Tags: r, shiny, r-plotly

in a interactive plot_ly the event_data saves the selected data.
With the below code, it is possible to reset event_data with double click on the plot

```
 output$brush <- renderPrint({
    d <- event_data("plotly_selected")
    if (is.null(d)) "Click and drag events (i.e., select/lasso) appear here (double-click to clear)" else d
  })
```

But how to reset event_data with a shiny button?

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

If the `source` argument of the plot is set to `XXX` (the default is `A`), then you have to set the input `plotly_selected-XXX` to `NULL`. This can be done with the help of `shinyjs`:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  actionButton("reset", "Reset"),
  plotlyOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output[["plot"]] <- renderPlotly({
    df <- data.frame(
      x = c(1,2,1), 
      y = c(1,2,1)
    )
    df %>%
      plot_ly(
        x = ~x,
        y = ~y,
        source = "A",
        type = 'scatter',
        mode = 'markers',
        marker = list(size = 20),
        showlegend = FALSE
      ) 
  })

  observeEvent(input[["reset"]], {
    runjs("Shiny.setInputValue('plotly_selected-A', null);")
  })

  observe({ # just to test
    print(event_data("plotly_selected", source = "A"))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This resets the `session$userData$plotlyInputStore[['plotly_selected-XXX']]`, but it does not actually update the highlighted data on the graph (see this [plotly.R/shiny.R source](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/blob/9ee548023bba6d68dd953f46485b2e611026766b/R/shiny.R#L200)).

Do you know of any way to also programmatically update the highlighted values on the graph?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by replacing

```
runjs("Shiny.setInputValue('plotly_selected-A', null);")
```

with

```
runjs("Shiny.setInputValue('plotly_click-A', null);")
```

if you register a clickable event using `event_register()`.

Adapting the above code

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  actionButton("reset", "Reset"),
  plotlyOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output[["plot"]] <- renderPlotly({
    df <- data.frame(
      x = c(1,2,1), 
      y = c(1,2,1)
    )
    df %>%
      plot_ly(
        x = ~x,
        y = ~y,
        source = "A",
        type = 'scatter',
        mode = 'markers',
        marker = list(size = 20),
        showlegend = FALSE
      ) %>%
    plotly::event_register('plotly_click')    
  })    

  observeEvent(input[["reset"]], {
    runjs("Shiny.setInputValue('plotly_selected-A', null);")
  })

  observe({ # just to test
    print(event_data("plotly_selected", source = "A"))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```